# How do I increase the UDP receive buffer size?

Tags: networking, kernel

I have a computer that communicates with a camera via UDP connected with a physical cable (no router or switch). The camera acts as the UDP server with the computer as client. Once in a while my Java APP hangs while an image is being transferred, line by line. My Java software waits for a line of the image that is never received and I believe this could be caused by receive buffer overflow.

I've tried to increase the receive buffer maximum size in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max 1000000
```

My program requests 7000000 bytes but at runtime reports that it received only 212992 bytes.

When I try to ask the OS the min, default, and maximum size:

```
$ sysctl -a | grep usb 
net.ipv4.udp mem 185535    247780  371670
```

How do I get a larger buffer? 
Is `sysctl` even being read?

Comment: Please eddit with UDP errors output from <code>netstat -su</code> this will show us how many UDP datagrams lost due to buffer overflow.

Comment: I'll try netstat -su the next time it fails, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Type:

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608
```

This sets the max OS receive buffer size for all types of connections.

from [Linux Networking Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/device_drivers/intel/ixgb.html)

> #### Resolving Slow UDP Traffic
>
> If your server does not seem to be able to receive UDP traffic as fast
>   as it can receive TCP traffic, it could be because Linux, by default,
>   does not set the network stack buffers as large as they need to be to
>   support high UDP transfer rates. One way to alleviate this problem is
>   to allow more memory to be used by the IP stack to store incoming
>   data. For instance, use the commands:
>
> ```
> sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=262143
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=262143
> ```
>
> to increase the read buffer memory max and default to 262143 (256k -
>   1) from defaults of max=131071 (128k - 1) and default=65535 (64k - 1).
>   These variables will increase the amount of memory used by the network
>   stack for receives, and can be increased significantly more if
>   necessary for your application.

Comment: Thanks, k500, i entered command in terminal - no change.  Edited sysctl.conf, rebooted (JIC), rmem_max was not changed.

Answer (score 0):

The edit to /etc/sysctl.conf was in error, it should have read as below and I should have increased the default value as well:

```
net.core.rmem_max=1000000
net.core.rmem_default=1000000
```

I don't know why the below wouldn't work when I entered it by hand but I wanted the values to be set at boot anyway.

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem 1000000
```

Comment: You need to do sudo with sysctrl

Comment: Thanks, VoteCoffee, If I ever get back to the office and that computer I'll give it a try!