# Game dedicated server application crash/delay after some time on Ubuntu 18.04 - xfce4 GUI

Tags: networking, games, crash, process, sockets

I've been running a game server application which, after some time, crashes with all the people connected to it (packets delay for one/two minutes making most people disconnect although the application stays open, recovering itself for new people connections thereafter).

The server is running on a VPS with one vCore, 2 GB RAM and 100 mbps network bandwidth. I've monitored the resources, and when game server is full, CPU is working at about 60%, while the RAM always at about 30%. Upload consuming about 10 mbps.
Firewall disabled.

It's the Assetto Corsa dedicated server which I'm talking about.

NOFILE ulimit set to a big value.

Should I follow this post solution, or it's useless for this issue?

[How do I increase the UDP receive buffer size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115636/how-do-i-increase-the-udp-receive-buffer-size)

Last thing, I've seen others run this application on Ubuntu 16.04. Would 18.04 ver. cause these issues?

I've changed provider too, the result has been that the server crashed after 2 days than after 1 day with the previous provider.

Here there are the logs at the moment of crash.

```
2021-05-20 20:42:34,760: PAGE: /cq/kehulistajax.php
2021-05-20 20:42:35,131: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,132: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:35,331: PAGE: /check.php
2021-05-20 20:42:35,608: PAGE: /api/wallet/redDetail
2021-05-20 20:42:35,632: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,632: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:35,655: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:35,734: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:35,891: PAGE: /h5/
2021-05-20 20:42:35,939: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,939: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:35,983: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,983: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:36,094: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:36,175: PAGE: /index.php/Wap/Api/getBanner
2021-05-20 20:42:36,269: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:36,269: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:36,450: PAGE: /index.php/Wap/Api/getSystemNotice
2021-05-20 20:42:36,830: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:37,344: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:37,617: PAGE: /script/public.js
2021-05-20 20:42:37,775: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:38,157: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:38,157: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:38,559: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:40,130: PAGE: /api/site/getInfo.do
2021-05-20 20:42:40,214: New connection from &{{14664763300}}
2021-05-20 20:42:40,214: SOCKET NO DELAY SET
2021-05-20 20:42:40,215: PAGE: /locale/Goex/zh/common.js
2021-05-20 20:42:40,219: PAGE: /JS/loginstatus.js
2021-05-20 20:42:40,465: PAGE: /base/goexjs
2021-05-20 20:42:40,622: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:40,834: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:40,918: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:41,171: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:41,171: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:41,178: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:41,178: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:41,359: PAGE: /other/codepay/js/codepay_util.js
2021-05-20 20:42:41,429: PAGE: /anquan/qgga.asp
2021-05-20 20:42:41,679: PAGE: /statics/js/API.js
2021-05-20 20:42:41,796: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:41,797: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:41,930: PAGE: /common/download.js
2021-05-20 20:42:42,712: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:43,977: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:43,988: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:44,353: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:44,857: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:44,868: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:44,868: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:44,970: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:45,186: PAGE: /config
2021-05-20 20:42:45,376: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:45,376: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:45,822: PAGE: /user/login
2021-05-20 20:42:46,100: PAGE: /zz2/address.php
2021-05-20 20:42:46,722: PAGE: /
2021-05-20 20:42:47,831: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:47,832: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:48,667: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:48,696: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,017: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,191: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:51,192: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:51,438: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,641: PAGE: /style.css
2021-05-20 20:42:51,994: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,994: PAGE: /js/json.js
2021-05-20 20:42:52,096: PAGE: /api/currency/quotation_new
2021-05-20 20:42:52,174: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:52,174: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:52,178: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:52,178: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:52,241: PAGE: /Content/css/wzwstylel.css
2021-05-20 20:42:52,279: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:52,562: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
- - - - - - -  other example of crash logs - - - - - - - -
2021-05-10 14:47:38,480: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-10 14:47:38,657: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-10 14:47:38,827: ERROR on SendTCPPacket: write tcp ipxxx:9722->ipxxx:43602: write: connection timed out
2021-05-10 14:47:38,827: ERROR on SendTCPPacket: write tcp ipxxx:9722->ipxxx:56621: write: broken pipe
2021-05-10 14:47:38,827: ERROR on SendTCPPacket: write tcp ipxxx:9722->ipxxx:63440: write: broken pipe

many many more for 1/2 minutes

EDIT: I've seen also a no route to host error added to connection timeout and broken pipe.
```

I've seen on the code above strange strings like "PAGE: /api/wallet/redDetail".

What does they mean? They don't mean nothing for the game application, seems like an interference with the system.

Strings like this one are not seen during normal game server running.

I think this is a good hint for understanding the issue.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: consider that the game process starts with few mb of ram used, then after two days arrives to about 90mb of ram used and many open files (last time I've checked has arrived to about 2000 open files).

Comment: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavor desktops), so you're asking about a release that reached it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a recent UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April)

Comment: No didn't think about that, @guiverc. I don't think influences the issue I'm talking about here though.